# The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found in WCF Service Application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0

When I am trying to use "var" in the WCF Service application it is giving error "The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Can you show us some code / config ?? We can't read your mind (or your screen), really....

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You get this error if you try to use `var` in a class member, e.g.:

```
public class Foo
{
    var a = 4;
}
```

`var` can only be used inside a method, not in classes, fields or method signatures.

See also: [Why no var on fields?](https://ericlippert.com/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/)

Comment: The reason is that the C# compiler can't infer what type `a` is. It might be an `int`, but it could be any other class that has an implicit cast to an `int`, like a `double` or `MyCustomClass` or `SomeEnum`.

Comment: @neontapir - That isn't very accurate. 4 is an `int` literal. `var a = 4;` is well defined and works as expected in a method's body. It's just that you can't use it outside of a method.

Comment: OK, fair enough. The usage example above didn't lend itself to what I was trying to say. I should have created a new one. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would imagine its because your targeting a framework before c#4.0. Try to go to your projects properties and set the target framework to 4.0

Comment: It is the compiler that matters here, not the target runtime. VS2008 and above should be fine, no matter which target runtime (unless the language compatibility options are enabled = *exceptionally* rare).

Answer (score 4):

For my ASP.NET 3.5 project, I had to make sure that I had the 3.5 framework compiler setup in my web.config file like:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
      <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a wild guess here, *but*: `var` may only be used for local variabels (inside a method).

Are you using it to define instance variables?

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure, you are building your service for .NET 3.5 or higher. The "var" keyword was not supported before.

Comment: It is the compiler that matters here, not the target runtime. VS2008 and above should be fine, no matter which target runtime (unless the language compatibility options are enabled = *exceptionally* rare).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you accidentally call `csc.exe` from a directory you don't expect? I solved the problem by running `csc.exe` using full path:

```
set csc=c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
%csc% try.cs

rem This was wrong:
set path=%path%;c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
csc.exe
rem This shows csc version, which turned out to be from Framework 2.0.
```